# Using index in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select ranges from an excel workbook to paste at certain locations in a word document template. I have a table in sheet 3 that has a column with Table1 then the cell next to it is empty. Table1 is written in the word document in the place where I want table one to be pasted. I have the following code to try and select the range of each table based on the header number of the table and loop through all tables. Any help would be appreciated, If you have another method let me know. This is the code I have so far.

```
Sub Auto()

Dim cell            As Range
Dim rng             As Range
Dim wdApp           As New Word.Application
Dim wdDoc           As Word.Document
Dim wdDoc2          As Word.Document
Dim FilePath        As String
Dim FilePath2       As String
Dim ending          As String
Dim rngPara         As Range
Dim Prompt          As String
Dim Filesave        As String
Dim FileSave2       As String
Dim CL              As Range
Dim rngg            As Range



'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler


'FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
'FilePath2 = Left(FilePath, InStr(FilePath, "\Calculations") - 1)
'FileName2 = "Disclosures Temps.docx"
'StrDoc = FilePath2 & "\Input" & "\" & FileName2
'Set wdDoc2 = wdApp.Documents.Open(StrDoc)

Set rngPara = Sheet3.Range("A1:Z1058").Find("Table Key")
If rngPara Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Table Key column was not found."
    GoTo ErrorHandler
  End If
Set rng = Sheet3.Range(rngPara, rngPara.End(xlDown))
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "" Then Exit For
    For i = 6 To Sheet3.Range("TableNumber").Value
        rownum = WorksheetFunction.Match(Format(i, "0"), Range("A:A"), 0)
        rownend = WorksheetFunction.Match(Format(i + 1, "0"), Range("A:A"), 0) - 1
        rowww = rownum & ":" & rownum
        coll = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.Range("4:4") = "", 0)
        colnumber = WorksheetFunction.Match(True, WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("4:4") = "", 0), 0) - 1
        ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, colnumber).Address, "$")(1)
        rng.Cells.Offset(0, 1).Value = "A" & rownum & ":" & ColLetter & rowend
    Next i
Next
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of the worksheet with the tables?

Comment: The excel sheet has several tables numbered 6 to 24 (this number can change but will always start with 6), with each table having a different row and column number. all tables are in one sheet and they all have a purple fill color for the headings

Answer (score 0):

You can access named ranges/tables in Excel VBA through the worksheets [`ListObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject) collection.  Knowing that we can loop through the worksheets and then through the ListObjects property to access each table.  From there you can search for a key if you like or you can go off the name of the table instead which might be easier and paste where you want in the Word document.

The example below is meant to be run from the Word document directly but you can adapt to run from Excel instead.  The example opens the Excel workbook containing the tables, loops through the worksheets and their ListObjects collection, copies the tables, and pastes them to the bottom of the Word document.

```
Sub InsertTablesFromExcelToEndOfDocument()
    Const strWorkbookPath As String = "C:\temp\search.xlsm" 'the name and path of the workbook
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlBook As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim xlTable As Object
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strWorkbookPath)
    xlApp.Visible = False
    
    For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets()
        For Each xlTable In xlSheet.ListObjects 'Use ListObjects to access Named Table Ranges
            Debug.Print "Worksheet Name: " & xlSheet.Name
            With xlTable
                Debug.Print "-- Table Name:  " & .Name
                Debug.Print "-- Table Range: " & .Range.Address
                Debug.Print ""
                
                .Range.Copy
                With ThisDocument.Content
                    .InsertParagraphAfter
                    .Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
                End With
                
            End With
        Next xlTable
    Next xlSheet
    
Cleanup:
    xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

---

### Update

The following update is an adjustment to the previous code with some code to search for the table name in the document and paste the corresponding tables there.  I went with surrounding the table names with angle brackets just so that it is less likely to mistake real content for the table placeholders

```
Sub InsertTablesFromExcelAtPlaceholders()
    Const strWorkbookPath As String = "C:\temp\search.xlsm" 'the name and path of the workbook
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlBook As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim xlTable As Object
    Dim myRange As Range
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strWorkbookPath)
    xlApp.Visible = False
   
    For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets()
        For Each xlTable In xlSheet.ListObjects 'Use ListObjects to access Named Table Ranges
            'Debug.Print "Worksheet Name: " & xlSheet.Name
            Debug.Print "-- Table Name:  " & xlTable.Name
            'Debug.Print "-- Table Range: " & xlTable.Range.Address
            'Debug.Print ""
            
            Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
            myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="<" & xlTable.Name & ">"
            While myRange.Find.Found = True
                xlTable.Range.Copy
                myRange.Paste
                    
                Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
                myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="<" & xlTable.Name & ">", Forward:=True
            Wend
        
        Next xlTable
    Next xlSheet
    
Cleanup:
    xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

---

> Can I alter the code to work for a certain range that is not necessarily a table. like I want to specify the range like from the header to the last empty row and from column A to the last empty column. Is this possible?

Sure this is possible, but I would recommend converting the range to a named table instead if possible which would greatly simplify things.  You're either defining this range there in the Excel workbook or directly in the code.  It's easier to manage if you can define the range and the placeholder outside of the code rather than dipping into the code every time you need to define a new table range.

But back to your question, I think it would be easier to answer if I understood this "Table Key" idea you have.  In the code you are looking through what looks like the whole spreadsheet for this "table key" however in your post you say "I have a table in sheet 3 that has a column with Table1 then the cell next to it is empty.".  So is your table key actually the first cell in this column you mention?  It would be helpful to see an example of the table and this key.  If you're interested you can edit your post and add a screenshot or two.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Can you tell me how can I alter the code for it to paste at a specific keyword. Like for example, If I have a range named table1 and a keyword in the document named as table1 where I want the table to be pasted.

Comment: I also wanted to ask how Can I alter the code to work for a certain range that is not necessarily a table. like I want to specify the range like from the header to the last empty row and from column A to the last empty column. Is this possible?